# Mockito Matchers any Map

Tags: java, testing, mockito

How can I use any map in mockito? I tried with following codes

```
when(mockedService.patch("1", Matchers.<Map<String, Object>>any())).thenReturn(object);
```

and with:

```
when(mockedService.patch("1", anyMap())).thenReturn(object);
```

But it returns:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
```

It works only when I put `any(String.class)`:

```
when(mockedService.patch(any(String.class), Matchers.<Map<String, Object>>any())).thenReturn(object);
```

But I want to have option of puting actual values instead of any String

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't mix matchers and non-matchers. Instead of `"1"`, use [`Matchers.eq("1")`](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)). This creates a matcher that matches any string equal to "1", which satisfies both your needs (equal to "1") and Mockito's (both arguments are matchers).

Comment: `You can't mix matchers and non-matchers` <- THIS